How to setup proxy for pipx that runs behind an intranet
I am in an intranet of company, in installing a package by pipx, it keeps running with a rotating icon but no actual progress. I am expecting something being installed to ~/.local/bin, but there is nothing added to the location. 
I am using an Ubuntu 24.04. 
I tried running following command, while the expected ~/.local/bin is always empty. 
$ pipx install conan 
⣯ installing conan 
$ ls ~/.local/bin -a 
.  ..

It turns out that exporting http_proxy and https_proxy environment helps. Please run following commands before doing the pipx install. 
$ export http_proxy=http://your.proxy.com:port 
$ export https_proxy=http://your.proxy.com:port
